# find earliest date of object with another condition in mongodb using javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Right now, say I have a database defined in a model file as:

```
MessageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  message:       String, 
  sessionRef:     { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Session' },
  dateCreated:      { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

In another file, I declare the message as:

```
var Message  = require("../models/message");
```

Now, I want to create a query using mongoose that finds the earliest message with a specific sessionRef. So for example:

```
Message.find({sessionRef : 123456})
```

This can be used to find messages with a specific sessionRef, but how do I actually find the earliest message (sorted by dateCreated)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to sort by earliest date would be:

```
Message.find({sessionRef : 123456})
 .sort({'dateCreated': 'desc'})
 .exec(function(err, messages) {
     //first item is a earliest message
 });
```

or if you want return only one item you can use `findOne`:

```
Message.findOne({sessionRef : 123456})
 .sort({'dateCreated': 'desc'})
 .exec(function(err, message) {
     //the message is the earliest
 });
```